# Are conjugacy classes of compact groups Borel?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff topological group. Is it necessarily the case that every conjugacy class of $G$ is Borel? It's certainly true if $G$ is countable (in which case $G$ is actually finite and the result is trivial) or if $G$ is abelian (in which case each conjugacy class is a singleton so the result is again trivial since $G$ is Hausdorff). I haven't been able to come up with much beyond that; any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, conjugacy classes are *compact* (and thus closed, since $G$ is T2). The map $\rho:G\times G\times G\to G$, $\rho(x,y,z)=xzy^{-1}$ is continuous and $\operatorname{conj}(z)=\rho[\Delta\times \{z\}]$, where $\Delta=\{(x,x)\,:\, x\in G\}$ is the diagonal of $G\times G$. Since $G$ is T2, $\Delta$ is closed in $G\times G$ (and therefore compact).

Comment: Thanks! Could you also have said the following? Take some $z \in G$. The function $g \mapsto gzg^{-1} \colon G \to G$ is continuous because $G$ is a topological group. The conjugacy class of $z$ is the image of this function, hence compact. Then the Hausdorff condition only needs to be used once (to conclude that this compact set is closed); have I made an error?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk You are right. I was, in fact, considering that argument too (which proves that orbits are compact provided that $G$ is compact), but then I decided that it wasn't quite worth editing the answer.